# Getting an Rsync error: “The remote path must start with a module name not a /”

Tags: rsync

I am trying to run rsync command to get files from my friend's pc to mine. I run following command-

```
rsync -avz /tftpboot/ root@192.168.18.2::/tftpboot/
```

I receive following result-

> ERROR: The remote path must start with a module name not a /
> rsync error: error starting client-server protocol (code 5) at main.c(1635) [sender=3.1.1]

Comment: Are you trying to connect to the remote computer (192.168.18.2) over ssh, or over the native rsync protocol?

Answer (score 2):

Please check `/etc/rsyncd.conf` file. The rsync command will require `module_name` as prefix to the path like-

```
rsync -avz /tftpboot/ root@192.168.18.2::module_name/tftpboot/
```

The `/etc/rsyncd.conf` file contains module_name in square brackets like one mentioned below:

`rsyncd.conf`

```
[Module_Name]
auth users =
path = /
read only = no
uid = nobody
gid = nobody
use chroot = true
uid = root
transfer logging = true
```

For more details refer to following link-
https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsyncd.conf.html

Answer (score 0):

```shell
rsync -avz /tftpboot/ root@192.168.18.2::/tftpboot/
```

You can remove the double comma and turn it into:

```bash
rsync -avz /tftpboot/ root@192.168.18.2:/tftpboot/
```

This will probably make it work but might not be exactly what you're after. See comment by https://superuser.com/users/129262/mgutt.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The two colons have a special meaning: Use rsync daemon instead of SSH. So your answer is sadly wrong.

Comment: Yes and no. In my case I didn't want to use the `rsync` daemon, I just wanted to get the files from the remote server → thus pragmatically speaking it was a working solution.